# std::lock how do I know it failed

Tags: c++11, locking

[It is not clear from the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/lock/?kw=lock). This template function returns void. The document mentions -

> If the function cannot lock all objects, the function first unlocks
>   all objects it successfully locked (if any) before failing.

But how should the caller know it has failed ? 
Does it block until it is successful  and exception is the only failure scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It throws an error on any issue.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock)

As a couple other SO members have mentioned to me in the past on my own questions, steer away from **[CPlusPlus.com - The Canonical Reference for Misinformation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/lock/?kw=lock)**.

Please take this as an opportunity to learn the differences between [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). C requires return codes or side-effects to function arguments, while C++ offers [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) in addition to the aforementioned.

## Parameters

(none)

## Return value

(none)

## Exceptions

> Throws std::system_error when errors occur, including errors from the
> underlying operating system that would prevent lock from meeting its
> specifications. The mutex is not locked in the case of any exception
> being thrown.

## Notes

> lock() is usually not called directly: std::unique_lock and
> std::lock_guard are used to manage exclusive locking.

## Example

> This example shows how lock and unlock can be used to protect shared
> data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
 
int g_num = 0;  // protected by g_num_mutex
std::mutex g_num_mutex;
 
void slow_increment(int id) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        g_num_mutex.lock();
        ++g_num;
        std::cout << id << " => " << g_num << '\n';
        g_num_mutex.unlock();
 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(slow_increment, 0);
    std::thread t2(slow_increment, 1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: std::mutex::lock is not the same as std::lock. The first locks a specific mutex, while the latter locks multiple mutexes whilst avoiding deadlock from locking them in the wrong order. I think you are trying to answer a question about the wrong one.

Comment: @John5342 Yeah, my answer was slightly tangential to what OP is asking about. Still, `std::lock` throws exceptions on errors: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock